# How to turn a Future into a stream for a ListView

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using this AutoCompleteTextField

https://github.com/sharansingh00002/Auto-Complete-TextField-Flutter

As shown in the example it calls a Future with a URL to pull the data, which populates the dropdown typeahead results.

I need to use the returned data also in another ListView, not just the dropdown of the autocompletetextfield.

My question is how to turn the Future `getLocationSuggestionsList` into a Stream so I can use a StreamBuilder for the ListView?

```
Future<List<String>> getLocationSuggestionsList(String locationText) async {
    final bloc = BlocProvider.of<EditProfileBloc>(context);
    List<String> suggestionList = List();
    LocationModel data = await bloc.fetchLocationSuggestions(locationText);
    if (data != null) {
      for (Predictions predictions in data.predictions) {
        suggestionsKeyValuePairs[predictions.description] = predictions.placeId;
        if (!suggestionList.contains(predictions.description))
          suggestionList.add(predictions.description);
      }
      return suggestionList;
    } else {
      return [''];
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use FutureBuilder instead of StreamBuilder in that case.

Comment: Futures are for a one time request correct? This function is called everytime a user stops typeing. So I guess since the method is called each time they stop I can use a FutureBuilder?

Comment: I see. You can do it with FutureBuilder and setState method but it will be a bit messy. You can turn the future into a stream by using asStream() method on the Future.